# Pi Zero W as AP

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I want to use Pi Zero as a compact router for classroom work. It can be quickly powered up and swithed off. It can both host some small web, and also serve as pathway to the Internet, as it is connected to WiFi router the student's do not have access to.

So I set up WiFi AP+station solution, using this: https://imti.co/iot-wifi/

With some trouble (had to manually install docker, as the install script failed to install a working version) I've got it up and running:

- it establishes an AP where clients can connect to
- it connects to the local WiFi router and receives IP address over DHCP
- it can access the Internet (tested with wget) without any issues

However, when the students are using the Pi as access point, they can not access (using web browser) any other address than the access point IP.

The author of the solution appears apparently has no time for maintain/support, so it's not clear where to turn for help or clarifications. Maybe the author did not intend to give access to the internet for those who connect to it's AP? After all, that would be sort of abusive to use some IOT gadget as a router, he just wanted to provide a way how to connect to the device in order to set up its connection to the network, and that's it. But I am really looking for a way to enable the router functionality.

Comment: `apparently has no time for maintain/support` or it works just fine for what it is, i.e. it's not broken, so nothing needs to be fixed. `Maybe the author did not intend to give access to the internet` probably not, since the goal was to create `IOT hotspot based configuration API` - try searching for something else

Comment: I do not understand why you are using this IOT docker thing. Just to make a wifi repeater you can look for example at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into other options. Whatever that lets me to power it up at random location and quickly configure it to connect to the local WiFi.